# changing address of the webservice during the execution

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a windows application which uses a  webservice.I need to added the webservice url dynamically depending on the environment it is using(TEST/DEVLOPMENT/PRODUCTION).
The changed url should be reflected in the app.config ,refrence.vb.current i am using the configure service reference option .But every time i need to change the environment i need to chanfer the addressand build the solution.
Is there any way i can have the address changed without building the solution.

when we use the configure service reference option whch all files are updated with the new address??
(app.config,refrence.vb,reference.svcmap,configuration.svcinfo,configuration91.svcinfo )

Thanks !!!

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Why don't you just setup 3 different environments.  Why do you need to generate the url dynamically?

Comment: its a client requirement..i dont want to generate it i want to set it dynamically

Comment: Your comment makes no sense.  The client requirement is to generate it dynamically but you want to set it dynamically thats exactlly the samething.  **Besides its YOUR JOB to tell your client what is and is not possible.**